# Hibernate Could Not Load an Entity Error

Tags: hibernate, coldfusion, railo

I just started using Hibernate on a new project, and with my first entity, I got an error, that I can't seem to figure out.

My schema right now is just two tables, continents and countries, where country has a continentid foreign key.

When I try to run code that calls the continents entity, I get a blank page.  All processing just stops, but no error is displayed.  When I run the code through MXUnit, I actually get an error.  The error message is simply `Could Not Load an Entity: [continent#1]`.  The cause of the exception is `org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException`.  That is all the I get.

My actual entity code is:

Continent.cfc

```
component tablename='continents' persistent=true output=false{
    property name='id' type='numeric' fieldtype='id' datatype='integer';
    property name="name" type='string' length='45';
    property name='bonus' type='numeric';
    property name='countries' type='array' fieldtype='one-to-many' cfc='Country' singularname='country' inverse='true' fkcolumn='continentid' cascade='all-delete-orphan'; 

    public Country function init(string name='', numeric bonus=0){
        setName(Arguments.name);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Country.cfc

```
component tablename='countries' persistent=true output=false{
    property name='id' type='numeric' fieldtype='id' datatype='integer' generator="identity";
    property name="name" type='string' length='45';
    property name='continent' fieldtype='many-to-one' fkcolumn='continentid' cfc='Continent' missingRowIgnored=true;

    public Country function init(string name=''){
        setName(Arguments.name);
        return this;
    }
}
```

And the code that calls the method.  It is in a ColdSpring bean

ContinentBean.cfc

```
component {
    property name="continent" type="any";

    public any function init(any continent=''){
        if(len(Arguments.continent))setContinent(Arguments.continent);
        return this;
    }

    public any function getContinent(){
        return continent;
    }
    public void function setContinent(numeric continent){
        continent = EntityLoad('Continent', Arguments.continent, true);
    }

    public void function setMapService(mapService){variables.instance['mapService'] = Arguments.mapService;}
    public any function getMapService(){return variables.instance['mapService'];}
}
```

I couldn't find any information really about the error message that I could understand, so this could simply be an invalid syntax thing.

Comment: the only thing that looks odd to me is 'datatype'.  I never used it and I thought there's only `'ormtype'` and `'sqltype'`.  Can you try removing that and do an `ORMReload()` and see if it work?  Also, look carefully in the stack trace, sometimes you'll see something useful there.  And turn on ormsettings.logsql to check if the generated SQL makes sense at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was that I was using the wrong attribute to specify the table name to be mapped in the objects.  The attribute should be table='' so my hibernate objects should look like this:

Continent.cfc

```
component table='continents' persistent=true output=false{
}
```

Country.cfc

```
component table='countries' persistent=true output=false{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be the case that table structure is different from what is been mapped in java class.

Answer (score 0):

What does your database schema look like?  I've seen SQL Grammer execptions thrown when the datatypes in your objects don't align with the datatypes in your datamodel.

Answer (score 0):

What's your DB engine ?
Can we see your orm application config ?

Personally I have never seen the property `'datatype'` and I didn't find it in the documentation.
I recommend you to use `'sqlType'` if you want to force the data type. Typically I use it with datetime :

```
property name="creationDateTime" type="date" sqltype="datetime";
```

I have to specify `sqltype="datetime"` because `type="date"` is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the configuration `ID` is provided with the data type explicitly.

For example, change this:

```
<id name="id" column="ID"/>
```

To  this:

```
<id name="id" column="ID" type="java.lang.Long"/>
```